# AS2 Nested Child MC gotoAndPlay Another Child Movie Clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How do I gotoAndPlay a frame number of a child MC from another child MC?

I have a movieclip that has 4 nested child movieclips.
mcA - mcB - mcC - mcD
Inside mcC at the end of the movie clip I am trying to gotoAndPlay a specific frame inside mcB.

I have tried:

```
MovieClip(_root).mcB.gotoAndPlay(181);
```

and

```
mcB.gotoAndPlay(181);
```

but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would have to be on the first frame in order to access an instance name that isn't visible to the stage yet. You could put it in the first frame and set _visible=false - then you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand coorectly, and `mcC` is a child of `mcB`, then all you need on the last frame of `mcC` is:

```
_parent.gotoAndPlay(181);
```